# Detect if file is open locally or over share

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I'm trying to check if a file is open in Win32:

```
bool CheckFileUnlocked(const TCHAR *file)
{
    HANDLE fh = ::CreateFile(file, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    if(fh != NULL && fh != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        return (CloseHandle(fh) == TRUE);
    }
    return false;
}
```

I need to be able to distinguish if a file is opened locally, in that case the function must return `true` against if it is opened from a shared path. The file itself is accessible over network, and is mapped in a shared drive. The function above tries to open file with exclusive access. I tried adding else clause reducing to:

```
bool CheckFileUnlocked(const TCHAR *file)
{
    HANDLE fh = ::CreateFile(file, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    if(fh != NULL && fh != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        return (CloseHandle(fh) == TRUE);
    } else {
        fh = ::CreateFile(file, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
        if(fh != NULL && fh != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            return (CloseHandle(fh) == TRUE);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But I still couldn't figure out if the file was open locally or over network on another system. I also tried `LockFileEx()` and `UnlockFileEx()`, but I'm guessing these might be wrong approaches. How do I solve this without actually querying the Application (`LibreOffice Writer`), assuming it provides API level access to this condition (LO actually provides a popup upon opening said document and allows to open it as ReadOnly, or open a Copy)?

Comment: [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why do you think you need to know this? What is the larger problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Even if you get this solved, you'll find yourself in a pretty bad spot: Now you have a [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) race.

Comment: I agree about the TOCTOU race issue.

Comment: I don't agree with the XY comment here: it's dismissive. Immediate task at hand might be to provide some kind of custom UI popup, to show perhaps the Application's awareness about the condition. Coming to the big picture: Does Win32 provide distinction between files accessed on a Windows filesystem, over network, and locally, can I enquire about the process details accessing this?

Comment: PS: Also, kindly notice that I didn't emphasize much about LibreOffice, nor did I add hashtag for the same.

Comment: Yes there [are differences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) specifically: *"When an application creates a file across a network, it is better to use `GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE` for `dwDesiredAccess` than to use `GENERIC_WRITE` alone. The resulting code is faster, because the redirector can use the cache manager and send fewer SMBs with more data. This combination also avoids an issue where writing to a file across a network can occasionally return `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`."*

Comment: I feel that this is an XY problem because I am unable to see *why it should matter* whether a file is open locally or via the network -- or, in fact, why it should matter that the file is open in another process *at all*. It would help, for starters, if you explained why it is necessary for your program to behave differently in these various circumstances.  (If the answer to this question is "because I don't want to clobber work being done by someone else" then I put it to you that cooperative locking, automatic invocation of "save as", and merge functionality are a better solution.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `GetFileInformationByHandleEx`:

- `FileRemoteProtocolInfo` should return properties of network access, and probably should fail on local files
- `FileStorageInfo` should return properties of the storage, it might fail on network (but need to verify that)

Comment: Re: `FileRemoteProtocolInfo`, the return value (i.e. the error code) is Win32ErrorCode.ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER (87) when the supplied handle does not have remote protocol properties.